# Hibernate not working Intellij driver not found

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc, intellij-idea

I have a web application and I´m trying to get Hibernate working.

As soon as I call my webservice, which uses Hibernate, I´m getting the error

> org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver  could not be loaded

I´ve read some posts on SO, where the solution was to add the driver to the classpath.

What I first did is, I´ve added the dependency to my pom.xml, but afterwards it did not download any libs, so I downloaded it manually with maven.

Now I´ve "mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar" in my libs and added the stuff to my project.

But it had no effect.

Afterwards I´ve copied the lib to my TOMCAT/libs folder which also had no effect.

Why can´t the driver be loaded and how can I fix it?

My hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproject</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">hibernate</property>
    <property name="connection.password">hibernate</property>
    <mapping class="database.DevicetableEntity"/>
    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
</session-factory>
```

Comment: Can you show your hibernate.cfg.xml ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your connection settings. Sorry to ask that by have your restarted your server after put the JAR file on the proper direcotory? yourapplication/WEB-INF/lib/jargoeshere